# Shiny Server does not start and returns Trace/breakpoint trap

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, shiny-server, raspberry-pi2

I thought I had successfully installed Shiny Server on my Debian Wheezy (Raspbian). I got no errors in the `cmake` and all other required packages were also installed. I followed the instruction on
[Building Shiny Server from Source](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Building-Shiny-Server-from-Source).
If I enter `shiny-server` I see a long log followed by`Trace/breakpoint trap`. 
One error that occurs says: `var OutOfCapacityError = 0x2e608091 <undefined>`
I stored the log [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jmkoc9rf0xxjeqt/ShinyLog?dl=0)
Any ideas on what causes this?

Answer (score 2):

I got Shiny Server running on a Ubuntu image on my RPi. The (8GB) image is available here: https://github.com/trestletech/RpiR#images . Though I happen to work for RStudio, this is certainly not an officially supported architecture/environment.

You'll not it's hosted on the RpiR package, which is an R interface to the WiringPi library that allows you to do digital/analog reading and writing on the Rpi's GPIO pins.

I unfortunately did not document the process of installing very well, so I don't have much guidance for you in getting started. There are a couple of known issues on Shiny Server with Debian in general (you'll not that it's not officially supported), so Ubuntu is probably going to be an easier starting point, but there were a few other hacks I had to take along the way that I didn't record, unfortunately.

If there's sufficient interest, I can try to recreate the steps in a more reproducible way so you can use more than just this one image.

Comment: I'd love to see that. Or to be a test bunny in trying to reconstruct the process. I'm ending up with the same Trace/breakpoint trap as shown above

Comment: @Jeff Allen I'd also love to see a reproducible guide on how to do this if you're willing. I feel like I'm getting really close on Minibian (Debian Jessie), but can't seem to get it working. I'm happy to post where I'm up to, but if Ubuntu works, I'm also happy to switch over and run under that.